# how to execute iojs command from php as a root?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-14.04

i am trying to execute an iojs command from php using php "exec" function. I change the permission of my file to "root" and also tried to execute it with "sudo". but nothing worked.

Comment: This sounds like something you really don't want to do. Perhaps explain the situation a bit more, there might be better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem. I added the specific application to sudoer file.